# How to use complete disk space in the lvm - CentOS

Tags: centos, rhel, lvm, vmware

I have created a new physical volume using `/dev/sdb`. I ran `lsblk` command and following is the output.

```
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
fd0           2:0    1     4K  0 disk
sda           8:0    0    80G  0 disk
├─sda1        8:1    0     1G  0 part /boot
└─sda2        8:2    0    79G  0 part
  ├─cl-root 253:0    0 547.8G  0 lvm  /
  ├─cl-swap 253:1    0   7.9G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  └─cl-home 253:2    0  23.3G  0 lvm  /home
sdb           8:16   0     1T  0 disk
└─cl-root   253:0    0 547.8G  0 lvm  /
sr0          11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

size of the disk `sdb` is `1TB`. But When I created new physical volume, `cl-root` became only `547G`, it is expected to have `1T+`. How do I add remaining `500GB` to `cl-root`

**Edit:**
Output of `sudo lvs`

```
 LV   VG Attr       LSize    Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
home cl -wi-ao----   23.33g
root cl -wi-ao---- <547.79g
swap cl -wi-ao----   <7.88g
```

Comment: Please add the output of `sudo lvs` to your question.

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa Added the output for `sudo lvs`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pvresize /dev/sdb
lvextend -r -l +100%FREE /dev/cl/root
```